# Почему не удается удалить узел?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Краткий смысл:
Идут по XDocument в цикле, проверяю условие и если оно истинно, то удаляю узел:

```
        bool flag = false;
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(kvp.Value);
        var childs = xDoc.Root.Elements().ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < childs.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (childs[i].Attribute("id") == null) continue;
            if (!dict1.ContainsKey(int.Parse(childs[i].Attribute("id").Value)))
            {
                flag = true;
                childs[i].Remove();
                i--;
            }
        }
```

Ловлю такую ошибку на попытке удаления:

> Additional information: Родительский элемент отсутствует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно менять индекс, ведь вы не изменяете материализованную коллекцию `childs`.

Попробуйте так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < childs.Count; i++)
{
    if (childs[i].Attribute("id") == null) continue;
    if (!dict1.ContainsKey(int.Parse(childs[i].Attribute("id").Value)))
    {
        flag = true;
        childs[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм... Вроде, работает. Получается, что при декременте попадал на убитый узел.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну да.